# What is is mean that an " Integral of an odd function converges to 0"

Tags: calculus, probability, improper-integrals

I can add more context if it is needed, but long story short, I needed to find the expected value of a random variable $X$, by its marginal density function from its joint density function with r.v. $Y$. The marginal density function was $f_X(x) = 5x-1000x^3 $, so $E(X) = \int_0^\infty x(5-1000x^2)dx$. I had thought this integral diverged but apparently the converges to $0$. When I had looked it up, it had something to do with it being an "odd function. Can someone help explain what that means

Comment: Probably the integral is actually from $-a$ to $a$ for some number $a$, not from $0$ to $\infty$. Such an integral $\int_{-a}^a f(x) dx$ is always $0$ as soon as $f$ is an odd function.

Comment: And the integral, as written down in your question, diverges (converges to $-\infty$.)

Comment: I agree with @TorstenSchoeneberg, but I will add that you have to be careful : it is not because $f$ is an odd function that $\displaystyle \int_{\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) dx$ necessarily converges. For example, $\displaystyle \int_{\infty}^{+\infty} x dx$ diverges. However, if $\displaystyle \int_{\infty}^{+\infty} f(x) dx$ converges, with $f$ being an odd function, then its value is necessarily $0$.